# Post data with curl with no Content-Type header

Tags: curl

If I do

```
curl -v --data "hello" example.com
```

curl sends

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

hello
```

I know that I can pass `-X 'Content-Type: something/else` to change the value of the Content-Type header, but is there a way to send data without that header being set at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell curl to not send a header at all, pass the header with no value using `-H`, like this (the quotes are not strictly necessary):

```sh
curl --data hello -H 'Content-Type:' example.com
```

this will send this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 5

hello
```

From the [curl man page for the `-H` flag](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-H):

> Remove an internal header by giving a replacement without content on the right side of the colon, as in: `-H "Host:"`. If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated with a semicolon, such as `-H "X-Custom-Header;"` to send "`X-Custom-Header:`".